# how to serve mpegts stream for m3u8 with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, m3u8, mpeg2-ts

I have some `mpegts` files `0.ts`, `1.ts`, `2.ts` that I put on a server and I want to play those files as an `m3u8`. The `m3u8` looks like the following:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:6.25,
http://example.com/ngx/0.ts # <-- this works
# http://example.com/express/0.ts # <-- cant play m3u8 if changed to this line
#EXTINF:6.25,
# http://example.com/ngx/1.ts  # <-- this works
http://example.com/express/1.ts  # <-- this also works
#EXTINF:6.25,
# http://example.com/ngx/2.ts # <-- this works
http://example.com/express/2.ts # <-- this also works
#EXTINF:6.25,
# http://example.com/ngx/3.ts # <-- this works
http://example.com/express/3.ts # <-- this also works
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

`http://example.com/ngx/0.ts` serves the ts file put under `/var/www/html` with `nginx` server, the response header from postman looks like the following:
[image: response header from postman of ts file served by nginx]

`http://example.com/express/0.ts` is an `express.js` server which serves the ts file as follows:

```
res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "video/mp2t" })
fs.createReadStream(tsFile).pipe(res);
```

and the postman response header looks like:
[image: response header from postman of ts file served by express.js]

I could play the ts files downloaded individually from the `express.js` server, however, when I changed the first url in `m3u8` to download from the `express.js` server instead of the `nginx` server, the `m3u8` cant play.

I suspect it has something to do with the format or meta info of the file that is served from the `express.js` that the stream is not correctly recognized by `m3u8` as `mpegts` data. Please advise how I can serve the ts file correctly as stream.

Comment: Can you not compare the files? Are the sizes different?

Comment: After downloading the file, the sizes are the same compared locally. But the http responses have different sizes and headers.